# Why even when I don’t create a turtle object in python my code works

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am new to python and I am currently learning turtle module. And as long as I understand turtle is a module in which we have `Turtle` class, so doesn’t this mean that first we need to create a `Turtle` object to use methods on this objects.

Like:

```
my=turtle.Turtle()
```

But when I just import turtle and write `turtle.forward(50)` this works but I didn’t create any `Turtle` object, can someone please explain why this also works?

Comment: Yes, you would think so, but I think that `Turtle` cheats and creates a default turtle for you. I think its supposed to be easier for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the file `turtle.py`, If you don't create an object and call a function directly , it will create an object for you.

In the file [turtle.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/turtle.py) you can see in line 128 it defines a list `_tg_turtle_functions` of all the functions of a Turtle object.

In line 3856 you can see clearly that they eval an object and call the specific function you want.

Answer (score 0):

As quarmarana wrote in the comments, this is simply a convenience for beginners.  If you're curious about how this works you can actually see it [in the code for the turtle module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b8544e18e61a0f4a873b3f4b4b2211822584b63f/Lib/turtle.py#L3940) though it's a bit opaque as it's using some code generation hacks.

For most of the main methods on the `Turtle` class (e.g. `Turtle.forward`) it generates a `forward()` function that's essentially just a wrapper for initializing a `Turtle()` and calling `forward()` on it.